# How to assign a pointer to base class to an object of a derived class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, radix, assign

This is kind of hard to explain, so here is an example:

```
class A
{
...
}

class B: public A
{
...
}

vector<A *> v;    // contains pointers to objects of both type A and type B

B item1;

item1 = *v[0];    // *v[0] in this case is an object of type B
```

Except I get an error saying `no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘B’ and ‘A’)` and `no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘A’ to ‘const B&’` even though I would check to make sure that v[0] is of type B before I assign it to item1.

I realize that this would probably create problems if I was trying to assign an object of A to an object of its derived class, but that's what the check is for.  How do I get around this?  Do I need to do something completely different, or overload an operator or something similar to that?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The title sounds pretty weird! What should such operation achieve?!?

Answer (score 7):

```
item1 = *v[0];
```

The assignment above doesn't work because the static type of dereferencing `v[0]` is `A`, and you're attempting to assign it to a `B` object.

If you know that `v[0]` contains a pointer to a `B` object, you can `static_cast` it.

```
item1 = *static_cast<B*>(v[0]); // note that a copy is stored in item1
```

If you don't know whether `v[0]` contains a pointer to `A` or `B`, you can test it using `dynamic_cast`

```
auto ptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(v[0]);
if(ptr) {
  item1 = *ptr;
}
```

For the `dynamic_cast` to work, your `A` class must contain at least one `virtual` function.

---

Finally, the usual advice against storing raw pointers in containers. Assuming you're dynamically allocating the objects within `v`, instead of `vector<A*>` you should use `vector<unique_ptr<A>>`. Also, if you're going to `delete` these objects via an `A *`, then the destructor of `A` needs to be `virtual`.

```
class A
{
  ...
  virtual ~A() = default;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) does.

```
if ( B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(v[0]) )
{
    item1 = *b;    // *v[0] in this case is an object of type B
}
```

Comment: I thought this had something to do with it.  Thank you!

Comment: @ikh: Yes, it's possible to declare variables inside the controlling statements of loops (which is very common for `for` loops) and also conditionals.